# How to filter entity inside entity in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to find what other way to code in repository. I hope you encounter this kind of scenario. I have entity transportation entity result.

```
  - id
  - user
     - id
     - name
     - address
  - emails[] 
     1-{
       email,
       date 
     } 
     2-{
       email,
       date 
     } 
     3-{
       email,
       date 
     }
```

But I need the last email of arrays, and this is the display that I need in my API

```
 - id
 - user
   - id
   - name
   - address
 - emails[] 
   3-{
      email,
      date 
   }
```

I have here my repository, this will display the list of transportation but the emails are not filter into last email.

```
/**
* display transportation list
*/
public function findById($id){

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->leftJoin('t.emails', 'e')
            ->where('t.id = :id')
            ->setParameter(':id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()[0];

}
```

I don't know if [Criteria](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) is useful on this part by filtering the email into DESC and get the last part. But if you have suggestion on how to do this. I'll be glad to study for it. I don't have an idea on how to fix this. I already did putting the last() function in my transportation entity. but my boss want it to add that function in my transportation repository. Now, I'm searching on how to fix this.

Comment: You may consider using `LexikFormFilterBundle` in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your entity, the field `$emails` is an instance of `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection`. This interface contains a bunch of useful methods that help finding elements inside a collection. One of this method is `last()`, which will return the last entity in the collection.

You can add a public method to your entity that will give you the last email:

```
public function getLastEmail()
{
    return $this->emails->last();
}
```

It's not guaranteed that the emails will be sorted by ID, but you can force this by adding `@ORM\OrderBy({"id"="ASC"})` annotation to `$emails` field (or an analogous configuration in YAML, if you use YAML files for mapping).

Comment: I did that, but my boss want to add it in my transportation repository not in transportation entity. I dont have any idea on how to do that. some codes are doing the same as yours

Comment: You'd have to write a custom query that uses `JOIN` with an inner select, sth like `JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM emails GROUP BY transportation_id`. But that's an overkill. Using the collection method is much simpler. If your boss's concern is optimization, he should probably learn about [3 rules of optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization).

Comment: I will check for that. I will search it first that code. sorry not familiar